# Maximum USB 2 length (printer in another room)

Tags: usb, wiring

I want to run a printer in another room in my house WITHOUT networking.  My needs require a direction USB connection.  Will I have trouble running a USB beyond a certain length of cabling?

Comment: This is close to off topic, but the general question of how long a USB cable can be is very useful for any EE that is running into issues. I am not closing this as a very good question for USB. I would like the answer accepted to have references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used a 15'  USB extension cable successfully to bring my printer to the oposite side of my office. Beyond that you can get a [USB repeater cable](http://www.usbcables.com/Extension_cable_USB_15ft/)

Answer (score 4):

5m is the maximum officially supported cable length, and you can chain several cables using at most five hubs, which gets you at most 30m.

http://www.usb.org/developers/usbfaq#cab_sol

Comment: So once I hit 5m, I can use a powered hub and get another 5m (per output on the hub) up to 30m (per chain) with identical performance to a single 5m cable?

Comment: Only every other hub needs to be powered. There are even 10m cables with a hub in the middle. The performance shouldn't depend on cable length.